# Graph API: How to paging multiple ids request?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am struggling with the following problem:
I am making multiple ids requests to facebook graph api. For example, my request is :
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5//posts?limit=999&since=1459126186&fields=fa,fb&ids=IDXXX,IDYYY

Facebook returns a anwser with two pagging objects, one to each id.
`

```
{
    IDXXX: {
        data: [{
           fa:xxx,
           fb:xxx
        }],
        paging: {
            previous: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/IDXXX/posts?fields=likes.summary%28true%29&limit=999&since=1459307679&__paging_token=enc_AdA85rNpPYHvktNzGlxIYRH0P9iv4MtA7sTLBbcnmSZAcNATv47eZAMwOFIWzT76ffsCHs4I9sMLTlOxK5gRaJUr4yUbOKzFkyOekV1yfmY0CYbwZDZD&__previous=1",
            next: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/IDXXX/posts?fields=likes.summary%28true%29&limit=999&since=1459124473&until=1459211851&__paging_token=enc_AdBHTjfCRf8228pfS5uUTgTgTg0JIZBAzDEV0CyITdZANjFc1B83UuQOr4gZAsPaW56xxHw4t8jYWEdrZCZAjGXZAaHdZAvE6vLk2z6LGHskWeNCIL7egZDZD"
        }
    },
    IDYYY: {
        data: [{
            fa:xxx, 
            fb:xxx
        }],
        paging: {
            previous: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/IDYYY/posts?fields=likes.summary%28true%29&limit=999&since=1459663229&__paging_token=enc_AdD9byAcNJmeihHEyH7smQoq0nK2NWA0v8ASgBhOnPZCcnNKfx5EmCWmQpKgUGZB17k1jYBEqMHA03lZA97mzZA4etsIA0MICB0L305GpSdUH5muCQZDZD&__previous=1",
            next: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/IDYYY/posts?fields=likes.summary%28true%29&limit=999&since=1459124473&until=1459297105&__paging_token=enc_AdBqOXaIR44LAEoAvBSB2K5pzCLCuLw6NeA9PVaTdK7DTuZA05ys1gRi0cvFLEapBQJXZC2SvuQxrZCaW4kzIFZBHOy5A7rJ3oGiRBkCltJHh8ZBqRAZDZD"
        }
    }
}
```

`

Now I really don't know how to procceed. If it was a request to only one id it would be easy. But how do I keep requesting both ids using both pages?

Comment: Do batch queries instead.

Answer (score 0):

I added limit=1000000 after all the fields, so I never get anything in paging.

Comment: Do this really work? When I tried to set a big limit Facebook just returns the first 100 objects.